# Change Content or Include File Without Refreshing Page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I've a menu and a content div. Content div is not displaying. When user clicks a menu item, content div shows and page smooth scrolls to top of the content div. Here is my code:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="section1">
        <a id="bir" href="#icerikBaslik">1</a> <!-- This -->
        <a id="iki">2</a>
        <a id="uc">3</a>
        <a id="dort">4</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="icerikDiv">
        <h1 id="icerikBaslik">Deneme</h1>
        <p>Random content</p>
</div>
```

When user clicks "a id 1, (commented by This)" #icerikDiv shows and page scrolls. With this jQuery methods:

```
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(selector).offset().top
  }, 1000);    
};

$(document).on('click', '#content a', function () {
    $('#icerikDiv').show();
    scrollToElement($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

So that's it for a menu item. Question is, I don't want to lose smooth scrolling and because of that I don't want page to be refreshed.

When user clicked another link, content of #icerikDiv must be changed. Page will still scroll to #icerikDiv but content will be different. This is what I want.

And if possible, I want to keep content datas in php files. Like "menu1.php", "menu2.php" etc.

When user clicks a link, can I include related php file into #icerikDiv without refreshing page?

I thought about:

- Give every link a specific method
- Inside them, show #menuXcontent and scroll to #menuXcontent
- Write down all content in same page, display:none;
- For example when clicked menu6 link, show #menu6content and scroll to it

But I didn't like this. I'm sure there is a better way.

Comment: Like this ? http://jsfiddle.net/VPzxG/

Comment: "Like" this but not this. Because your whole content is showing on the page. I don't want it to. 1st step: No content. 2nd step: User clicks a link. 3rd step: Show content related to that link scroll to that.

Comment: You have to use ajax for it.

Comment: I can't. I don't know it and time is too short. What if I use my own method (at the end of the question)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two main options. One is like you describe, to include all of the content in a single page and show it as needed. This is a viable solution which is used quite often. The advantage is that once the page loads it is very responsive, as it does not need to get data from the server when you click a link. The disadvantage is that the initial page load will be much bigger. It would generally work well for sites where the individual sections were quite small.

The second option is to use ajax to get your content from the server without a page reload. Ajax can be used to get data or html from your server. If you have a php file which gives the output you want in html, you can use the [.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) convenience method:

```
$( "#icerikDiv" ).load( "menu1.php" );
```

This will get the data from menu1.php and put it in to #icerikDiv.

To avoid hardcoding the php file, we can use a data attribute so that the source is declared on each link -
HTML:

```
<a id="bir" href="#icerikBaslik" data-content="menu-1.php">1</a>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#content a').click(function () {
        $( "#icerikDiv" ).load( $(this).data('content') );
        $('#icerikDiv').show();
        scrollToElement($(this).attr('href'));
    });
});
```

It might make more sense to put the div target on the data attribute and use href for the source php - but it will work either way.

Comment: but as you see, I show the div with an a.click event. how can I load and show and scroll in an a.click event? can you merge these codes?

Comment: What you would do is start the load when they click, and show the div when the load completes. Updated my answer with an example of how that might look.

Comment: I've used your code and lost smooth scrolling. Load worked OK.

Comment: EDIT: anyway I've changed your code, did not triggered a method on load php file, just called load and showed and scrolled, seems fine. Bu here is another problem now. It always calls menu1.php. How can we do this with parameters?

Comment: To do that you can use a data attribute on each link with the php file it should get the content from. Then read that in the click function. Updated above to show that.

Comment: I've written file names to name attribute and it worked (tried it before your comment). Do you think using data-content or name make difference about SEO or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can load content from a php file via ajax calls and append it to anywhere you want on the page using javascript.

Read up on ajax:
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

A simple example would be:

```
$("#loadcontent").on("click", function(e){
  $.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "loadcontent.php",
    success: function(content){
      $("#contentdiv").html(content);
    }
  });
});
```

This would change the content of `#contentdiv` into whatever is echoed from `loadcontent.php`.